# Inputing via pipe and writing input to a column in another file using awk

Tags: input, awk, pipe

I want to count the lines of a file using `wc -l` and write this number to a file (in a specific column) using awk.

`wc -l list | awk 'print $1'` gave me the output

```
68
```

I want to write this `68` to the **3rd column in another file.** (count.txt)

How it can be done via `awk`? (or are there better options?)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and add sample input and expected output. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Btw: see `wc -l list` and `wc -l <list`

Comment: @Cyrus Thank you, no need for another awk :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is fun... The strategy is to read the `ARGV[1]` and then blank it in `BEGIN` so that we read from stdin afterwards:

```
wc -l < list | awk '
    BEGIN {
        out = ARGV[1]
        getline < out
        line = $0
        close(out)
        ARGV[1] = ""
    }
    {
        wc = $0
        $0 = line
        $3 = wc
        print > out
    }
    ' count.txt
```

We could probably read from stdin in the beginning, but then we would have to cache `count.txt` in the body then print in `END`.